# Python module not found despite being installed poetry

Tags: python, import, module

I think poetry is somehow not in sync with my python compiler.

Running `poetry add bcrypt` etc. and then running python app.py I get

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bcrypt'`

This persists with some other modules, while seemingly it is working with some.

I set `poetry env use` to `which python` output, but it still does not work.

What could be wrong? I'm using linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

Which python version you used while installing module and while running the code, it should be same.

1. Check if the modules is present under Python{version}/lib.
2. If not try installing with the same python you are using try again.
3. If not there may be environment variable issue, set the same python version
   in ev